When using scipy minimize, a large array appears, which was not originally there, which leads to the error Unable to allocate 60.3 GiB
I need to minimize the Frobenius norm for the variable W. W has a dimension of (300,300), but after the first iteration of minimization, an error occurs that too large an array of dimension (90000,90000) does not fit into memory. The problem is that there shouldn't be such an array. I will be grateful for your help!
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def objective_function(W, X, d):
    W = W.reshape((d, d)) 
    #return (X - np.dot(W, X)).shape # shape = (300,120)
    return np.linalg.norm(X - np.dot(W, X), 'fro')

def estimate_background(Y, A_hat, C_hat, l, d):
    A_hat = A_hat.T
    T = Y.shape[1] # T == 120
    b0 = (Y - A_hat @ C_hat) @ np.ones((T, 1))
    X = Y - np.dot(A_hat, C_hat) - np.dot(b0, np.ones((1, T))) # X.shape == (300,120)
    W_init = np.zeros((300,300)) # d == 300
    result = minimize(objective_function, x0=W_init, args=(X, d), method='L-BFGS-B')

    optimal_W = result.x.reshape((d, d))

    return optimal_W

MemoryError: Unable to allocate 60.3 GiB for an array with shape (90000, 90000) and data type float64
I tried to use various methods to minimize it, but it didn't help. I assume this error is due to the minimization method, but I'm not sure.
Added code that can be run

import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def objective_function(W, X, d):
    W = W.reshape((d, d)) 
    #return (X - np.dot(W, X)).shape # shape = (300,120)
    return np.linalg.norm(X - np.dot(W, X), 'fro')

def estimate_background(Y, A_hat, C_hat, l, d):
    A_hat = A_hat.T
    T = Y.shape[1] # T == 120
    b0 = (Y - A_hat @ C_hat) @ np.ones((T, 1))
    X = Y - np.dot(A_hat, C_hat) - np.dot(b0, np.ones((1, T))) # X.shape == (300,120)
    W_init = np.zeros((300,300)) # d == 300
    result = minimize(objective_function, x0=W_init, args=(X, d)) #The error is in this line after the first iteration of minimization

    optimal_W = result.x.reshape((d, d))

    return optimal_W


Y_tmp = np.ones((300,120))
A_tmp = np.ones((3,300))
C_tmp = np.ones((3,120))
B = estimate_background(Y_tmp, A_tmp, C_tmp, 5, Y_tmp.shape[0])

MemoryError: Unable to allocate 60.3 GiB for an array with shape (90000, 90000) and data type float64
     13 X = Y - np.dot(A_hat, C_hat) - np.dot(b0, np.ones((1, T))) # X.shape == (300,120)
     14 W_init = np.zeros((300,300)) # d == 300
---> 15 result = minimize(objective_function, x0=W_init, args=(X, d)) #The error is in this line after the first iteration of minimization
     17 optimal_W = result.x.reshape((d, d))
     19 return optimal_W



Could you use the linear approach from this answer? It seems like minimizing np.linalg.norm(X - np.dot(W, X), 'fro') is equivalent to the least squares calculation W = np.linalg.lstsq(X.T, X.T)[0].T by the argument in the linked question. 2) Doesn't the identity matrix work as a solution to this objective function?


I tried to use various methods to minimize it?  What methods?  to minimize what?  For this you need to understand the error BEFORE trying fixes.

Show the full error message so you (and we) know exactlly where it's trying to create such a large array.  It would also help if you gave a [mcve].  That would make running test cases a whole lot easier!

Do you get this error with other methods?  Why did you choose this particular one?  Why no other keyword parameters to fine tune its performance?

I think this can be formulated as a convex QP problem. Large-scale QP solvers are readily available.

@hpaulj I tried to use other minimization methods that are offered in scipy. That's the problem, I don't understand why the error occurs.

@hpaulj Added minimally reproducible code

@NickODell To be honest, I'm not sure, but I'm just wondering where this error comes from here

You are working with arrays with shape (300, 300), but normally minimize expects one-dimensional arrays (i.e. vectors).  Viewed as a 1-d collection, your W has 90000 elements.  Some of the algorithms used by minimize will compute a Jacobian matrix for your problem, which will have shape (90000, 90000).  That is the shape reported in the error message. As also noted in the message, an array of double precision floats of that size requires 60.3 GiB.

@WarrenWeckesser Thank you, I understood the reason for this error! In this case, should I use another method to minimize this? I knew that scipy.minimize expects a vector, but I thought it was possible to work around it, but apparently not.

Solve as a QP with a QP solver. No gradients needed.

By the way, the MemoryError here is caused by an inefficient use of memory within SciPy, which is fixed in SciPy 1.14.0: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/20645
